# C++: How to declare private member objects

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-constructor, member

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you use the non-default constructor for a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088944/how-do-you-use-the-non-default-constructor-for-a-member)

I have the current code:

```
class ImagePoint {
private:
    int row;
    int col;

public:
    ImagePoint(int row, int col){
        this->row = row;
        this->col = col;
    }

    int get_row(){
        return this->row;
    }

    int get_col(){
        return this->col;
    }
};
```

And I want to do this:

```
class TrainingDataPoint{
private:
    ImagePoint point;
public:
    TrainingDataPoint(ImagePoint image_point){
        this->point = image_point;
    }
};
```

But this wont compile because the line `ImagePoint point;` requires the `ImagePoint` class to have an empty constructor. The alternative (from what I have read) says I should use a pointer:

```
class TrainingDataPoint{
private:
    ImagePoint * point;
public:
    TrainingDataPoint(ImagePoint image_point){
        this->point = &image_point;
    }
};
```

However, once the constructor has finished running will this pointer point to a cleared up object? If so, do I have to make a copy of the `image_point`? will this require a copy constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a constructor initializer list:

```
TrainingDataPoint(const ImagePoint& image_point) : point(image_point){
}
```

You should prefer this when possible. However, there are situations when you must use it:

- members with no default constructors (as you mentioned)
- member references
- `const` members

Comment: And this will make a copy of image_point and store it in point?

Comment: thanks, I will accept answer in 10 mins when SO lets me :).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know these things since you're not going to use that code, but just for completeness:

> once the constructor has finished running will this pointer point to a
>   cleared up object?

Yes, the parameter `image_point` is destroyed when the constructor exits. So you're right, it would be incorrect to store a pointer to it in the object and try to use it after that.

> If so, do I have to make a copy of the image_point?

That would do it, but the reason you're not going to use this code is the question of *where* you would copy it to.

> will this require a copy constructor?

Yes, but `ImagePoint` already has a copy constructor which the compiler generates automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you have read is wrong. The correct alternative is to use an initialisation list

```
class TrainingDataPoint{
private:
    ImagePoint point;
public:
    TrainingDataPoint(ImagePoint image_point) : point(image_point){
    }
};
```

By the way this has nothing to do with *private* members, you'd get the same issue if they were public.

Answer (score 1):

Just use constructor initializer lists:

```
class TrainingDataPoint 
{
private:
    ImagePoint point;
public:
    TrainingDataPoint(const ImagePoint &imgpt) 
         : point(imgpt)
    {
        // other code here as necessary. point has already been initialized
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the constructor initializer will fix your problem.

```
TrainingDataPoint(const ImagePoint& image_point) : point(image_point){
}
```