# Default constructor missing for a nested class in the copy constructor of a parent class

Tags: c++, class

I have a nested class structure, Class A is parent and Class B is nested under. 
When I compile the code, the copy constructor of Class A reports that there is no default constructor for the class B.

```
error: no default constructor exists for class "A::B"

class A{
   -------
   struct B{
     B(var1, var2){}
   };
   B b;
};

A::A(){ b = new B(Var1, Var2) } // default constructor
A::A(a){ } // copy constructor
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Where do you have an instance of `B`? Does only the copy constructor get the error?

Comment: Show us code that we can actually use and compile to get the same behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Where are you actually using `B`?

Comment: He gives you suitable code. Since he doesn't specify it, both of the constructors he shows for A will try to use a default constructor for B.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use the non-default constructor for a member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088944/how-do-you-use-the-non-default-constructor-for-a-member)

Comment: Now you are leaking memory with your `new` call

Comment: @UpAndAdam I have a delete in the destructor which I haven't mentioned in the post. Thats a good catch.

Comment: Wait, you mean `b` is actually a pointer? You really need to post actual code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a member initializer in both constructors:

```
A::A() : b(Var1, Var2) {}
A::A(const A& a) : b(Var1, Var2) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined a constructor taking two arguments `B(var1, var2)` as such a default constructor is not automatically provided for you.

So you have a couple of options.

#### Choice 1

Add a default constructor for `b` in your `struct B` definition

```
struct B{
    ....
    B() {};
}
```

also your syntax below is wrong it should be:

```
A::A() : b() {};
A::A( const A& a) : b() {};
```

#### Choice 2

You could use the non default constructor of B but you have to come up with values from somewhere

```
A::A() : B( valA, valB ) {};
A::A( const A& a) : b(valA, valB) {};
```

#### Choice 3

You probably don't want that and instead should create a copy constructor for `B` and do this

```
A::A( const A& a) : b(a.b) {};
```

Comment: `A` does not derive from `B`, but `A` does have a member named `b` that is of type `B`, so the initialization list in the `A` constructor needs to use `b()` instead of `B()`.